# Обработка данных внутри компонента React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Есть функция обработчик в компоненте React:

```
  const handleChange = () => {
    const values = getValues();
    setMainData(mainData => Object.assign(mainData,values));
    onSubmitParent(mainData);
    console.log(mainData);
  }
```

Так же есть кусок компонента:

```
<input ... onKeyPress={handleChange} />
```

Необходимо при вводе в инпут запускать функцию, передающую данные в след компонент (с этим всё нормально).
***Но, значение инпута(которое передается) не берет новые данные (только данные с прошлого шага).***
*Пример: при последовательном вводе "3+4", будет выводить {},{3},{3+}, хотя надо {3},{3+},{3+4}*
**Решение через setTimeout работает, но может есть другие способы?**

```
  const handleChange = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const values = getValues();
      setMainData(mainData => Object.assign(mainData,values));
      onSubmitParent(mainData);
      console.log(mainData);
    }, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Двустороннее связывание между компонентами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1388931/%d0%94%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Получить и передать данные не проблема, сами данные передаются устаревшими на один шаг. Пытаюсь разобраться почему

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1388941/385375 в этом ответе, есть простой пример как получать актуальные данные, запустите его, поиграйтесь и эксперементируйте :)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать)